# Safe init using failable guarded initializer

Tags: swift

I am wondering if that is a safe and proper init, with one failable init guarded and an init.

Are the force-unwrap correct in the `self.init` as I know they are those types ?

```
struct Item: Equatable {

            let id: NSNumber 
            let displayName: String
            let amount: NSNumber

            init(id:NSNumber, displayName:String, amount:NSNumber) {
                self.id = id
                self.displayName = displayName
                self.amount = amount
            }

            init?(dictionnary:NSDictionary) {

                guard let id = dictionnary["id"] , id is NSNumber else  {
                    return nil
                }

                guard let displayName = dictionnary["display_name"] , displayName is String else {
                    return nil
                }

                guard let amount = dictionnary["amount"] , amount is NSNumber else  {
                    return nil
                }


                    self.init(id:id as! NSNumber, displayName: displayName as! String, amount: amount as! NSNumber)
                }

}

func ==(lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

Comment: @Dex' ter: Re your edit: It *is* called "failable initializer" in Swift, not "fail-able", see for example https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17. – (However, my Mac autocorrects it to "bailable" :)

Comment: What's the reason you're using `NSNumber` and `NSDictionary`, as opposed to `Int` and `[String: Any]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The separation into a non-failable and a failable init method is 
fine.

The forced casts with `as!` are safe in your code, because it is verified before
that the three variables `id`, `displayName`, `number` have the
respective types `Number`, `String` and `NSNumber`.

However:

- The code is error-prone: Changes to the types must be done at two places.
- It is not immediately obvious that it works correctly.

Forced casts should (and can!) be avoided in most cases, in the
same way as forced unwrappings. The program would be terminated
immediately if the cast fails.

In your code that is quite easy,
by replacing the type checks `is T` by  conditional casts `as? T`.
The latter return a value of the type `T` and that makes the forced
cast unnecessary. In addition, it simplifies and shortens the code
of  the failable init method:

```
init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

    guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? NSNumber else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let displayName = dictionary["display_name"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let amount = dictionary["amount"] as? NSNumber else {
        return nil
    }
    self.init(id: id, displayName: displayName, amount: amount)
}
```

As a further simplification, combine the optional bindings into
a single `guard` statement (attribution goes to @Knight0fDragon who
reminded my in a comment):

```
init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {
    guard
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? NSNumber,
        let displayName = dictionary["display_name"] as? String,
        let amount = dictionary["amount"] as? NSNumber else {
            return nil
    }
    self.init(id: id, displayName: displayName, amount: amount)
}
```

Some other points:

- Your spacing is not consistent.
- The indenting is totally wrong.
- The correct spelling is `dictionary`.

Comment: not to be a jerk,  but couldn't all those guards be joined together so that you have 1 guard checking 3 variables, then if any of them fail, return nil.  This would reduce your lines of code even more

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: You are completely right, I wonder why I didn't think of it! – Are you going to post an answer?

Comment: no,  that is all yours buddy

Comment: yep makes sense ! and about the other point, messed it up when posting the code sorry..